# python сортировка массивов

Tags: python, массивы, dict

Есть массив **member_role** где указана **роль и ID пользователя**

```
member_role = {'@everyone': [269564120792039424, 472679205885313044, 766316425890889758, 987004547438366761], 'Кактус': [766316425890889758], 'Котя 3': [472679205885313044], 'Лисёнок': [269564120792039424], 'Лис': [987004547438366761], 'Микель': [269564120792039424]}
```

Есть второй массив **data** с **ID пользователя** и **количеством опыта у этого пользователя**

```
data = [(987004547438366761, 8.9), (269564120792039424, 500.5), (766316425890889758, 112.2), (472679205885313044, 4.5)]
```

Подскажите как можно получить третий массив подсчитав сколько у каждой роли в сумме опыта, в моей голове это выглядит так:

```
Третий массив = {["<Название роли 1>": "Количество опыта у всех её участников"], ["<Название роли 2>": "Количество опыта у всех её участников"], ["<Название роли 3>": "Количество опыта у всех её участников"]}
```

Если кто-то напишет код на языке python с объяснением буду очень признателен.

Comment: `member_role` - словарь. вам все-таки нужен массив или словарь  на выходе программы ?

Comment: из вашего примера следует, что у вас в голове третий массив выглядит как множество (set) списков. большого смысла  в этом нет. видимо вы все же имели в виду словарь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой алгоритм решения вашей задачи:

1. Преобразуем `data` в словарь вида `id: point`:

```
data_dict = dict(data)
```

2. Бежим по ролям `member_role`:

```
for role in member_role
```

3. Обнуляем сумму очков.

```
_sum = 0
```

4. Суммируем очки `id`, находящихся в этом списке:

```
for user_id in member_role[role]:
    _sum += data_dict[user_id]
```

5. Записываем значение:

```
res[role] = _sum
```

Answer (score 2):

то же решение только чуть короче код:

```
data = dict(data)
res = {k:sum(map(data.get, v)) for k,v in member_role.items()}

>>> res
{'@everyone': 626.1, 'Кактус': 112.2, 'Котя 3': 4.5, 'Лисёнок': 500.5, 'Лис': 8.9, 'Микель': 500.5}
```